# Is this a slipping clutch?

Tags: toyota, clutch, yaris

I have a 2000 Toyota Yaris 1L with 125k miles. The clutch was replaced at 85k miles.

I have noticed that over time, the biting/grabbing point of the clutch has moved up the pedal. It used to be quite deep but it's really close to the top position now.

I have also noticed that in 1st gear, sometimes if I apply a little bit too much gas while lifting the clutch, the car stutters/jumps forward and then goes. I need to apply the exact right amount of gas for that not to happen.

No other symptoms

Is my clutch going bad? Or is it something else?

Comment: Clutch pad is being worn. This should be a standard maintenance replacement and shouldn't be very costly.

Comment: If cable operated then it may need adjusting.

Comment: @Nelson How much do you think it will cost roughly? The car is pretty old and I have been looking for a new one but used car prices are too high at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the clutch is wearing, but is probably working just fine for the mean time.

If a clutch is truly going bad, it will slip. To test whether it's slipping or not, put it in 3rd or 4th gear and see if it bites and kills the engine or if it revs up before it catches and allows the vehicle to go forward. If it does the latter, your clutch is going away. You can also see when in higher gears if when you apply extra power, the engine RPM goes up, but the speed doesn't. No matter what gear you're in, if you've completely released the clutch pedal, acceleration should be completely linear with the engine speed. If you find the engine revving but the car not going faster, that's your clutch slipping with the need to be replaced soon.

Comment: No, I don't see any of those other signs. Car instantly stalls if I start to lift the clutch in 3rd or 4th without any gas. Engine speed is linear with acceleration. Does my clutch pad need to be replaced as others suggested?

Comment: @BoyRacer6483 - If you're not slipping, then no need to replace the clutch "pad" ... if they are suggesting that, then they really don't know what they're talking about. The clutch is installed as a unit, with a pressure plate, friction disk, and most often the flywheel (can be machined or replaced, depending on how bad it is worn). You don't just replace the "pad" (which I'm assuming they mean the friction disk).